# passing value from backbone.js to backend

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

```
var Song = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        name: "Not specified",
        artist: "Not specified"
    },
    initialize: function () {
        document.write("Music is the answer");
    },
    url:function(){
       return '/home/';
    }
});

var Album = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Song
});

var song1 = new Song({
    name: "How Bizarre",
    artist: "OMC"
});
var song2 = new Song({
    name: "Sexual Healing",
    artist: "Marvin Gaye"
});
var song3 = new Song({
    name: "Talk It Over In Bed",
    artist: "OMC"
});

var myAlbum = new Album([song1, song2, song3]);
document.write(myAlbum.models); // [song1, song2, song3]
```

1. How do i send `myAlbum.models` object to my Service.
2. How can i alert my url

Comment: What do you mean with: _"alert my url"_ ?

Comment: duplicated? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782510/backbone-create-multiple-models-in-collection-serverside/10788855#10788855

Comment: Agree with @fguillen. Here is a solution to doing bulk updates/saves. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5014216/best-practice-for-saving-an-entire-collection

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that [this post](http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/12/backbone-js-wine-cellar-tutorial-part-1-getting-started/) can help you out.

Answer (score 0):

to send Data to the Backend do follwing:

`myAlbum.save();`

it`s sending a POST (if its new data) or a PUT (if model has id) request to the server.

for more:
http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-save